# Click function not hit outside the loop function

Tags: javascript, jquery

As title above. My click event is not hitting when i click my button. I made my button via `JS Loop`. My click event function is in outside of my loop function. As I notice when i am debugging, when i try to put it inside the function of the loop the click function it's hitting properly now.

Is there any reason why?

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
    var docsLength = data.data[i].resultData;
    var title = data.data[i].resultData[i].Type.Description;
    var card = '<div class="card" id="HelloWorld_' + i + '"> <div class="card-header bg-success"><h3 class="card-title">' + title + ' </h3 ></div> <div class="card-body"> </div>'
    $("#card_documents > .card-body").append(card);

    for (var b = 0; b < docsLength.length; b++) {
        var id = "HelloWorld_" + i;
        var row = '<div class="row mt-2" style="font-size:20px">'
            + '<div class="col-md-1"><input type="checkbox" style="height:20px; -webkit-box-shadow:none" class="form-control flat mt-2"> </div >'
            + '<div class="col-md-1"> <input type="button" id="btnClickHello' + b + "" + i + '" value="Upload"></div>'
            + '<div class="col-md-10" style="color:green"> ' + data.data[i].resultData[b].Docs + ' </div >'
            + '</div >';
        $("#" + id + " > .card-body").append(row);
    }
}



$("#btnClickHello21").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("a");
});
```

Comment: You need to wrap your click event function into a document.ready function.

Comment: @Martin Not essentially..

Comment: @KiRa Why have you used the number '21' specifically for the click event? Is there any reason?

Comment: @JonesJoseph i will edit it soon. Its just my testing for now if it is working or not.

Comment: @Martin my whole code is inside doc.ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamically added elements, you need to use [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(".card-body").on("click", "#btnClickHello21", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("a");
});
```

Comment: like you said when element is dynamically added I should use `on` right?. Like on my problem?

Comment: @KiRa - Yes and make sure you bind the event the available parent element at the moment.

Comment: @KiRa - Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it (despite the 2 answers already), is by wrapping your click event function into a `document.ready` function.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#btnClickHello21").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("a");
    });
});
```

jQuery *document.ready* docs: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: And that doesn't work? I don't see the document.ready block in your question, so that's why I suggested it.

Comment: in my post i didn't include it. sorry

Comment: No problem, just wanted to point that out, despite the already 2 working answers that you received. Always good to have multiple angles to broaden ones knowledge. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are adding element dynamically, that is why `click` event is not working beacuse all `click` events get bind to DOM on load. To enable `click` on  dynamically added element you can use below code -

```
$('body').on('click', '#btnClickHello21', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("a");
});
```

This will work for all a tags with `#btnClickHello21` in the body, whether already present or dynamically added later.

Answer (score -1):

as per my knowledge it is not hitting because you are not wrapping your function within a document.ready(). DOM and function is loaded before you create a button.

you need a event delegation concept like.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btnClickHello21").on('click',function(){
            //do your stuff.
    });

})
```